# SVG Filter with a mask

Tags: svg, svg-filters

There is a filter

```
<filter id="filter">
 <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4">
 <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="">
</filter>
```

applied to image

```
<image filter="url('#filter')">
```

I have a certain shape:

```
<polygon points="">
```

How can I use the polygon as a mask where the filter is not applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `<image>` elements at the same location.

- The first image would have a filter (as you have it now).
- The second image would not have a filter, instead it would have a clip.
- The clipPath used by the second image will need to have the polygon as its contents.

If you really want one image, you could probably merge the images using canvas [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29) and then write out the composite image to a new `<image>` element.

Comment: This is how I have it currently done. I needed a solution with a single image, but if it's not possible then I'll take your answer as correct.

Comment: Use canvas to merge them then.

Answer (score 2):

You could also apply the filter to the polygon and then use feImage to import your image into the filter. Using feComposite "in" will do the masking.

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <defs>
  <filter id="cutout" x="-300%" y="-300%" height="700%" width="700%">
    <feImage result="photo" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/%D0%9D%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE.jpg/1280px-%D0%9D%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" result="blurphoto"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in="photo" in2="SourceGraphic" result="photomask"/>
    <feComposite operator="over" in2="blurphoto" in="photomask"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon filter="url(#cutout)" points="20,10 250,190 200,30 160,34 160,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```